# Force download of zip file stopping a few thousand bytes short

Tags: php, nginx, compression

I'm trying to start a force download of a zip file containing a large amount of images. I'm using php to force the download and it's running on nginx. The weird thing is when i use wget to download the file it usually works, but when I try and download it using a browser the file ends up being a few thousand bytes to small.  I have tried multiple file sizes with similar results.  I don't think it's a timeout error because i played with slowing down my download speeds and it always stops at the same place (on that specific file).  I have no idea why it would work on wget but not a browser. I have tried it on multiple computers (with different browsers) and multiple networks and got the same results. I have played around with the PHP code that is serving up the file and with php.ini and nginx settings to no avail. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions anyone might have, it would really help me out!

Here is my PHP code that is forcing the download:

```
    ob_end_flush();
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'.zip"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($archive));
    flush();
    readfile($archive);
```

where $archive is the path to the zip file the user is trying to download.

Comment: You really shouldn't be sending a file via PHP! You keep the PHP process busy for the entire file transfer and thus this will kill your server if you ever get popular. Please see here for how to do it properly: http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could your webserver be applying gzip Content-Encoding to the file you're outputting from PHP (or could you have enabled it in PHP itself eg `zlib.output_compression`)?  Zipping an already zipped file tends to make the actual file larger, so if the client reads the script's Content-Length header, it'll stop downloading before the "larger" zipped file is output.

`wget` does not support compression, so the server would not attempt to use Content-Encoding when you connect with wget.  Try it with `curl` and see if you get the broken file. If you use Chrome, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> to open the Developer Tools and go to the Network tab. While that's open, go back to the main window you opened it from and hit the link to download the file.  It should create an entry in the request list you can click on, which will open a subwindow with a "Headers" tab, where you can see if it had the `Content-Encoding:` line in the `Response Headers:` section.

BTW, I think you want to do `ob_end_clean()` there, rather than `ob_end_flush()` since `_flush()` sends the client anything you have in the buffer, while `_clean()` drops the buffer and any headers already in it.

Comment: Thank you! I turned zlib compression off for this page, and it fixed the download. Awesome answer. After I turned off zlib compression (using ini_set) my content-length header stopped working though. It's not showing up in the list of headers using firebug and my downloads won't give me a progress bar. would turning off output_compression have anything to do with it? Also do you know how i would be able to tell if my downloads are working because i turned off the compression or because the content-length header isn't showing up?

Comment: @Brian: Questions go in questions, not comments.  Ask separate questions for these other issues.